# Centralizer $C_G(T)$ of a maximal torus $T$ is in every Borel subgroup containing $T$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I read that if $T$ is a maximal torus of a connected algebraic group $G$, then $C_G(T)$ is in every Borel subgroup containing $T$.

I know $C_G(T)=N_G(T)^\circ$, the connected component of the identity in $N_G(T)$, hence is connected. Since $T$ is maximal, $C_G(T)$ is nilpotent, hence solvable, thus contained in some Borel group $B$. Then $T\subset C_G(T)\subset B$, so I get that $C_G(T)$ is in at least one Borel subgroup containing $T$.

How does it follow that $C_G(T)$ is in all of them? I know that Borel subgroups are conjugate, But if $T\subset gBg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$, I can't see why $C_G(T)\subset gBg^{-1}$ still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint: maximal tori of $gBg^{-1}$ are conjugate.

Comment: So $gTg^{-1}$ is also a maximal tori of $gBg^{-1}$, so there exists $gbg^{-1}\in gBg^{-1}$ such that $gbg^{-1}Tgb^{-1}g^{-1}=gTg^{-1}$, or equivalently, $bg^{-1}Tgb^{-1}=T$. So $bg^{-1}\in N_G(T)$. I don't know how to get to the centralizer though.

Comment: What you want is $gbg^{-1} (gTg^{-1}) (gbg^{-1})^{-1} = T$, so $gbTb^{-1}g^{-1} = T$. Then $gb$ normalizes $C_G(T)$ and $C_G(T) < B$, so $C_G(T) < gBg^{-1}$

Comment: From $gbTb^{-1}g^{-1}=T$, I see $gb\in N_G(T)$, so that $gb$ normalizes $C_G(T)$ follows since $C_G(T)=N_G(T)^\circ\unlhd N_G(T)$?

Comment: That's just $xC_G(T)x^{-1} = C_G(xTx^{-1})$, true in any group $G$ for any subgroup $T$.